# How to install Ubuntu-Personal development image on BQ M10 FHD?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, m10

Since the BQ M10 Ubuntu Edition was released, I bought this device right now.
I am using it more for playing around, than for real productive usage.
Is there a development image of Ubuntu-Personal for this device, that I can flash?

I already flashed back and forth Android and Ubuntu Touch, so flushing is mot a big deal.

Any idea, where I can download that?

Answer (score 2):

Just switch to the staging channel (using https://github.com/MariusQuabeck/magic-device-tool if you wanna). But be careful, it is not ready for an everyday use, and I had an hard time switching back to the «normal» channels. 
Good luck ;)

Comment: I flashed it and it is really not ready for every day use. Especially it's only working in portrait mode. After landscape login, it automatically rotates to portrait mode and you can not rotate it anymore.
But interesting is, that you can already install and use snaps. :-)